# Is there a way to check how much time it has taken to download a file using selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I was working on automation with selenium, i wanted to know if there is a way to check how much time the file has taken to download using selenium

Comment: Same way that you would measure the time it takes to do a generic something, I would imaging.  Call `System.nanoTime()` before and after, and compute the difference.  Refer to the javadoc.

Comment: Why would you use `selenium` to perform a native task like calculate _time the file has taken to download_? Using OS native calls would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge, there is no method to calculate the time to download. Instead of calculating time to download you can automate the system to wait until the next download completed.

```
do {

   filesize1 = f.length();  // check file size
   Thread.sleep(5000);      // wait for 5 seconds
   filesize2 = f.length();  // check file size again

} while (length2 != length1);
```

Hope this will help.
Further instructions refer the [java doc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.50.1/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html)